# Drupal 7 - How to create a contextual filter based on an aliased url

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

CASE:

I've created a content type 'Attorney', and have set a url alias pattern for all attorneys to be 'attorneys/[node:title]'. I'd like to create a view that uses the aliased path to display the information about the attorney. This view should have a 'page' display.

EXAMPLE:

When a user visits 'http://mydomain.com/attorneys/aaron-silber' the view returns data for the Attorney with the name Aaron Silber.

BACKGROUND:

I've searched high and low for a solution to this but can't seem to find one that works for me. Typically I'm asked to create a page view with a url of 'attorneys/%' and add a contextual filter with 'Content: Nid', choosing to provide a default value (type: Raw value from URL, path component 2).

The resources on the web for this case are aweful at best. Lets try to fix it here once and for all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Views block instead with the visibility set to "Only the listed pages" and supply "attorneys/*" in the textarea. Set the block to display in the main content region. Use the Content: Nid filter with a default value of path component 2, as you were previously attempting.

You can't have an attorney node page and a Views page occupying the same URL.